# Change theme of TimePickerDialog to use AppTheme

Tags: android

I have implemented a `TimePickerDialog` using the following code as given in [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePickerFragment):

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
```

}

I get a dialog like this one:

[image]

I want to change the theme of the `TimePickerDialog` to go with the `AppTheme` which extends an `AppCompat` theme. When i do use the other constructor as told by some, the theme works, but the `Dialog` goes fullscreen. The code i used for that was:

```
// Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.AppTheme, this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

I get this:

[image]

How do i go about this? - I want the `Dialog` to remain the same, but change only the accent colors. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` as `Parent Theme`

You need to define `Dialog` theme in `styles.xml`.

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/purple</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/orange</item>
 </style>
```

then use it like this:

```
// Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogTheme, this, hour, minute,
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Ah damn. Seems like i missed that. Thanks a ton! It worked.

Comment: I had to use `<item name="colorControlActivated"></item>` instead of `colorControlNormal`. Not sure why. But it worked!

Comment: Why it doesn't work if use Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert in values-v21 xml???

Answer (score 2):

**we can change the theme as shown in the below example.**

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Get a Calendar instance
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Get the current hour and minute
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    /*
        Creates a new time picker dialog with the specified theme.

            TimePickerDialog(Context context, int themeResId,
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener,
                int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)
     */

    // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
    TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,this,hour,minute,false);

    // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK
    TimePickerDialog tpd2 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,this,hour,minute,false);

    // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_HOLO_DARK
    TimePickerDialog tpd3 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK,this,hour,minute,false);

    // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
    TimePickerDialog tpd4 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,this,hour,minute,false);

    // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_TRADITIONAL
    TimePickerDialog tpd5 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL,this,hour,minute,false);

    // Return the TimePickerDialog
    return tpd;
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){
    // Do something with the returned time
    TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("HH:MM\n" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
}
```

}

for more detailed example see this [tutorial](http://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-timepickerdialog-theme.html)

i hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried this. But this enables us to use one of the in-built themes and not a custom one. What @rajesh said was what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You also may override the getTheme method like this:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    
    ...
  
    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.MyDialogTheme;
    }

    ...
}
```