# Change Theme of Time Picker - Android

Tags: java, android, timepicker

Attempting to change the theme of timepicker but unsure how its done. The code below works fine, just would like a different look (something like this[image].

Is it possible to change the below code by adding one the these themes

```
        THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK
        THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
        THEME_HOLO_DARK
        THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
        THEME_TRADITIONAL

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Private members of the class */
    private TextView displayTime;
    private Button pickTime;

    private int pHour;
    private int pMinute;
    /** This integer will uniquely define the dialog to be used for displaying time picker.*/
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    /** Callback received when the user "picks" a time in the dialog */
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                pHour = hourOfDay;
                pMinute = minute;
                updateDisplay();
                displayToast();
            }
        };

    /** Updates the time in the TextView */
    private void updateDisplay() {
        displayTime.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    .append(pad(pHour)).append(":")
                    .append(pad(pMinute)));
    }

    /** Displays a notification when the time is updated */
    private void displayToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ").append(displayTime.getText()),   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    /** Add padding to numbers less than ten */
    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Capture our View elements */
        displayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
        pickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);

        /** Listener for click event of the button */
        pickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        /** Get the current time */
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        pHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        pMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        /** Display the current time in the TextView */
        updateDisplay();
    }

    /** Create a new dialog for time picker */

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeSetListener, pHour, pMinute, false);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your `activity_main.xml` and  `style.xml`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713686/change-theme-of-timepickerdialog-to-use-apptheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this class:

```
 public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Get a Calendar instance
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Get the current hour and minute
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,this,hour,minute,false);

        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK
        TimePickerDialog tpd2 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,this,hour,minute,false);

        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_HOLO_DARK
        TimePickerDialog tpd3 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK,this,hour,minute,false);

        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
        TimePickerDialog tpd4 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,this,hour,minute,false);

        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_TRADITIONAL
        TimePickerDialog tpd5 = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL,this,hour,minute,false);

        // Return the TimePickerDialog
        return tpd;      //return your themed timepicker like tpd2, tpd3 etc..
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){
        // Do something with the returned time
        TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("HH:MM\n" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }
}
```

use it in your Activity as:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Initialize a new time picker dialog fragment
            DialogFragment dFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

            // Show the time picker dialog fragment
            dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"Time Picker");
        }
    });
```