# TimePickerDialog: Programmatically set colors without theme

Tags: android, timepickerdialog

We have a survey that is dynamically loaded and populated from a survey being displayed in an Android app. Colors, fonts, styles, etc. are being downloaded from the server.

It looks like you can set the `TimePickerDialog`'s `TimePicker`'s colors through themes ([Change theme of TimePickerDialog to use AppTheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713686/change-theme-of-timepickerdialog-to-use-apptheme)), but is there any way to set the accent color without a theme?

Answer (score 0):

You could use your own layout which uses a different color.

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(myContext, R.layout.my_layout, myListener, 0, 0, (android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(myContext));
```