# How to change timepicker theme without using TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am creating a timepicker inside a layout.I dont want to use a timepickerdialog.( [i got how to change theme in timepicker dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34714198/8660130))

My question is how to change theme of timepicker created inside a layout.
(Default theme is analog timepicker, but i want to have scrolling digital timepicker theme. i.e. theme 2 in timepickerdialog)

To change theme in this layout :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gislf.png)

To this theme (without dialog) :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1gUb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly a Theme, it as a TimePickerMode

You can set in the XML with:

```
android:timePickerMode="spinner"
```

Comment: I didn't know about such an xml attribute.But can i customize it ? I want the background in black and the text and spinner lines to be in blue.(as shown in pic in timepicker dialog).

Comment: The primaryColor is used as the color of the highlights, and the backgroundColor is the black

Comment: @Abhi, Got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

As Marcos mentioned in his answer, it is now possible to set the TimePicker style back to the old layout. They implemented a `timePickerMode` attribute for the TimePicker which can be set in the XML layout resource file.

The `TimePicker` can be `spinner` or `clock`. While the `DatePicker` can be `spinner` or `calander`

Source: https://gitlab.com/SaberMod/pa-android-frameworks-base/commit/3053b2fdcf7486f2e2f572f9b05ce65dacdd2b4c

[image]